# Passing props to the root component of Svelte

Tags: svelte, svelte-3, svelte-component

I understand that like in many front-end frameworks, Svelte allows the developer to separate logic into smaller, reusable component files. In doing so, you can pass props from a parent to a child component.

I would like to know if it is possible to pass props to the root component itself. I am trying to create a model using Svelte, and require some variables to be determined outside of scope of App.svelte (i.e. variables that are assigned at the same level that imports `bundle.js`)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There are 2 main ways to do this

#### Add data to the global scope

This leverages the global scope of the document to share values between different scripts. It basically boils down to just declaring something in the `index.html` and then later use it wherever you feel fit.

```html
<!-- index.html -->
<script>
  document.myapp = {
    name: 'Svelte'
  }
</script>
<script defer src="build/bundle.js"></script>
```

```js
// main.js
const app = new App({
    target: document.body,
    props: {
        name: document.myapp.name
    }
});
```

I use here the `main.js` because I like to keep all external informal close together in my apps, but in theory you can use `document.myapp.name` anywhere you want, even as default value for a store

```js
//store.js
export const name = readable(document.myapp.name)
```

One thing you have to make sure is of course that this object is initialized before the svelte app runs (otherwise it will all just be *undefined* or even crash)

#### Export and Call App

The second approach is to not run your App directly in your `main.js` but instead have another script call it instead.

```js
// main.js
import App from './App.svelte'
export default App
```

```html
<!-- index.html -->
<head>
    <script src='/build/bundle.js'></script>
</head>
<body>
    <script>
        new app({
            target: document.body,
            props: {
                name: 'from App'
            }
        })
    </script>
</body>
```

In this case it's important to make sure the script runs after the page has loaded and after the bundle has loaded (here I solved that by adding the script in the body tag and removing the *defer* from the bundle, there are better ways of doing this I guess)

Another important remark with this approach is that the name of your app is not necessarily what you exported from `main.js`, it is defined in your `rollup.config.js` in the output configuration as *name* (default is *app*)

```js
//rollup.config.js
output: {
  sourcemap: true,
  format: 'iife',
  name: 'app',
  file: 'public/build/bundle.js'
},
```